# erlang:start_timer/3 vs timer:send_after/3

Tags: erlang

What should I prefer:

```
erlang:start_timer(Ttl, self(), time_to_die)
```

or

```
timer:send_after(Ttl, self(), {timeout, time_to_die})
```

if my use case is to send a single atom message to a gen_server? I expect to have hundreds of thousands of gen_servers and each one of those will need to have an associated TTL timer event.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Common Caveats section of the Erlang Efficiency Guide](https://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/commoncaveats.html#timer-module) says:

> Creating timers using `erlang:send_after/3` and `erlang:start_timer/3`, is more efficient than using the timers provided by the `timer` module in STDLIB.
>
> The `timer` module uses a separate process to manage the timers. Before OTP 25, this management overhead was substantial and increasing with the number of timers, especially when they were short-lived, so the timer server process could easily become overloaded and unresponsive. In OTP 25, the timer module was improved by removing most of the management overhead and the resulting performance penalty. Still, the timer server remains a single process, and it may at some point become a bottleneck of an application.
>
> The functions in the `timer` module that do not manage timers (such as `timer:tc/3` or `timer:sleep/1`), do not call the timer-server process and are therefore harmless.